# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with or without www

Tags: php, jquery

I know what normally causes this but this is strange.

I am doing a jquery post in the following format:

```
$.post('relative/url/page.php', {key: val});
```

But I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

The error is saying that I am not using www in the post but the site is. I didn't think it mattered with relative urls as I have hundreds of other posts doing the same thing.

But then I tried using the full url with www and get the same error. It still says I'm posting without the www

So then I tried posting without www and of course it's the same error.

If I post to http://wwww.site.com it says the address in incorrect (obviously).

I am stumped.

EDIT:
I just realized whats really going on here. I am getting a 301 error (page permanently moved) and it is being redirected to the url without the www. So the real problem is what would cause that error? The page is definitely there.

Also if I run the post from index.html it works fine but if I do it from index2.html is when all of this happens.

Comment: Are you testing this on a webserver ?

Comment: yes. see edit for more info.

Comment: Are u in somehow using .htaccess?

Comment: Nope I'm not using any htaccess files.

Comment: I take that back. I found an htaccess file that was added by yeoman and that is what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP file you are requesting, add this at the top to make it a public resource :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *");
```

Or this to only allow your site.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://hello-world.example");
```

Comment: Tried this and didn't help but I found a deeper part of the problem. See post for edit.

Comment: Is the site on a subdomain?  Like beta.mysite.com?  @user3399110

Comment: no its www.mysite.com/index2.html. I have an identical page for index.html which works fine but index2.html which does the same exact post gets the redirect.

Comment: Hmm..  All I can think of is you got the relative path wrong.. Maybe I need to see more code.

Comment: It works fine if it is named index.html. As soon as I rename it to index2.html it gets the 301 when it posts. If the path was wrong I dont think it work work as index.html either.

Comment: Yeah,  then I would definitely need to see more code.

Comment: It ended up being an htaccess file i overlooked